# every time a new schema with empty tables were created why,how to eliminate this

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

my question is after exit ,when ever i run this boot class i am getting a new schema with empty tables all the previous data that was inserted into the database was getting deleted can anyone suggest a practice to over come this

```
package com.flp.fms.view;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.persistence.*;

import com.flp.fms.dao.FilmDaoImplForDB;

public class BootClass 
{
static BootClass bc=new BootClass();
static Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hello");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
UserInteraction ui=new UserInteraction(em);

public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException
{   
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println("1.AddFilm"+"\n"+"2.ModifyFilm"+"\n"+"3.RemoveFilm"+"\n"+"4.SearchFilm"+"\n"+"5.getAllFilm"+"\n"+"6.AddActor"+"\n"+"7.ModifyActor"+"\n"+"8.RemoveActor"+"\n"+"9.SearchActor"+"\n"+"10.getAllActor"+"\n"+"11.Exit");
        System.out.println("Enter your Choice");
        int choice = sc.nextInt();

        if(choice==11)
        {


        }
        bc.menuSelection(choice);
    }

}

private void menuSelection(int choice) throws ParseException
{
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:em.getTransaction().begin();
                ui.AddFilm();
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                break;
        case 2:ui.ModifyFilm();
                break;
        case 3:em.getTransaction().begin();
                ui.RemoveFilm();
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                break;
        case 4:ui.SearchFilm();
                break;
        case 5:ui.getAllFilm();
                break;
        case 6:em.getTransaction().begin();
                ui.AddActor();
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                break;
        case 7:ui.ModifyActor();
                break;
        case 8:em.getTransaction().begin();
                ui.RemoveActor();
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                break;
        case 9:ui.SearchActor();
                break;
        case 10:ui.getAllActor();
                break;
        default:System.out.println("Inavalid Menu Selection");
                break;
        case 11:System.exit(0);
                break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: have you set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property to create in hibernate properties? if yes then change it to validate

Comment: persistence.xml governs what is set and what happens. We don't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property to create in hibernate properties? if yes then change it to validate

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.

e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

[Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional)

Comment: <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>